# I can't get the previous td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, html-table

I know that it has been asked hundreds of times, but I can't find a way to get the previous `td` - probably because I'm a jquery beginner.

Here is my code:

```
findOverdue = function () {
  $("tbody").find("tr").each(function () {
    var paymentDate = $(this).find('td.paymentDate').text();
    var paymentDateTest = $(this).find('td.paymentDate').prev('td').text();
    var currentDate = $(this).find('td.currentDate').text();
    var isInitial = $(this).find('td.isIntial').text();
    var monthlyInstalment = $(this).find('td.monthlyInst').text();
    var penaltySize = $(this).find('td.penaltyPercent').text();
    var lastUpdated = $(this).find('td.lastUpdated').text();

    console.log("paymentDateTest: " + paymentDateTest);
  });
};
```

Now I'm trying to get the previous `td` value into the `paymentDateTest` variable without luck. I have tried few combinations without success. The console log is showing nothing. I know that I'm missing something really smal, but I'm not able to spot it.

**EDIT:**

HTML table:

```
<table class="dataTable" id="repaymentShedule">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <th>6</th>
                    <th>7</th>
                    <th>8</th>
                    <th>9</th>
                    <th style="display: none;">10</th>
                    <th style="display: none;">11</th>
                    <th>12</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: creditDetails">
                <tr>
                    <td class="paymentDate" data-bind="text: dateOfPayment"></td>
                    <td class="startBalance" data-bind="text: beginingBalance"></td>                        
                    <td class="monthlyInt" data-bind="text: monthlyInterest"></td>
                    <td class="principal"><input data-bind="value: princpalPayment"></input></td>
                    <td class="monthlyInst" data-bind="text: monthlyInstallment"></td>
                    <td class="ammountToPay" data-bind="text: ammountToPay"></td>
                    <td class="remainingBalance" data-bind="text: endingBalance"></td>
                    <td class="paid"><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isPaid, disable: isPaid, click: testFunc, value: true"></td> <!-- value: true moje da ne e nujno -->
                    <td class="currentDate" data-bind="text: currentDate"></td>
                    <td class="penalty" data-bind="text: penalty"></td>
                    <td class="isIntial" data-bind="text: isIntial" style="display: none;"></td>    
                    <td class="penaltyPercent" data-bind="text: penaltyPercent" style="display: none;"></td>    
                    <td class="lastUpdated" data-bind="text: lastUpdated"></td>             
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: A HTML sample would also probably help to resolve your issue

Comment: Edited. Sorry I was removing the useless code in order to make it easier for you. :)

Comment: can u provide table html?

Comment: It's not teh issue, I just removed some useless lines and probabbly I removed the `)};` by mistake

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan just edited

Comment: @Slim got it. What you want to get? `.text()` or the input `.val()` (value)?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I want to get `.text()`

Comment: @Slim but **you don't have any text**....

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan hmm, then How I'm able to get the `.text()` into the `paymentDate` variable? :O

Comment: @Slim you use `td.paymentDate` can you show me in your code Where is a `TD` element with **class** `.paymentDate` ?! So 2 main errors: you don't have any text and you're pointing to some inexistant class names.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41085/discussion-between-slim-and-roko-c-buljan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for this:

`var paymentDateTest = $(this).prev().find('td.paymentDate').text();`

Huge thanks to  `Roko C. Buljan` for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,if you have immediatly  preceding td

```
var paymentDateTest = $(this).find('td.paymentDate').prev().text();
```

Comment: What else sibling can precede a `td` element

Comment: he  may choose to contain any preceding hidden sibiling

Comment: :) What hidden sibling? Another `TD` just hidden?

Comment: anything he want apart from td since I don't know his html ,so I mentioned clear use of prev()

Answer (score 1):

I created to quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3FkZ/1/), Looks like

```
 alert($('.prevDate').prev('td').text())
```

is working.